# how to create a lambda function after find derivative of another lambda function?

Tags: python

I want to return a lambda function in check_Derivative like f in the main.

```
from sympy import *

def check_Derivative(f):
    x = symbols('x')
    my_f1 =lambda x:f(x).diff(x)
    return my_f1

f = lambda x: x**4 + x**3-3*x**2
f1=check_Derivative(f)
```

Comment: Looks like you are indeed returning a lambda function.  What's the problem?

Comment: `NameError: name 'symbols' is not defined` please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I recommend getting a good grasp on Python before introducing the complexity of `sympy` or whatever symbolic computation library you're using. Your `check_Derivative` function declares a symbol which is never used, then declares an (unrelated) lambda that evaluates a function and then calls the `diff` function on the resulting *value* of the function (presumably a number). This suggests to me that you're trying to learn sympy without a firm grasp of the basics of programming in Python.

Comment: `lambda x:f(x).diff(x)` creates a new name `x` in its declaration and it does not use the symbol `x` created above it